# KinectJS: contrast filter?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

Does anyone know if there is a filter similar to the below that will enable one to change the contrast and not just the brightness?

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-brighten-or-darken-image-tutorial/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here are the filters proposed by KineticJS :
http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Filters.html